# One or more errors occurred while processing template 'Entity.tt'

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Am using Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015, I have installed EF Power Tools as in [Installing EF Power Tools into VS2015](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/)

After that I was trying to run EF Reverse engineering code first approach, but I was getting the issue and resolved from [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 breaks EF reverse code engineer vsix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36863371/4286033)

When I have done this I am getting an issues now as **One or more errors occurred while processing template 'Entity.tt'.**
For this I have followed [One or more errors occurred while processing template ‘Entity.tt’.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/marafa/2013/09/15/one-or-more-errors-occurred-while-processing-template-entity-tt-using-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-vs-2012-update-1/)
And I have even added

```
Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True
```

In web.config and changed **Persist Security Info=True** in advanced tab, but still the issues isn't resolved am getting the same issue as in title.

**Need help/suggestions.**

Detiled error from visual studio output window.

```
One or more errors occurred while processing template 'Entity.tt'.
error : An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.ArgumentException: Empty path name is not legal.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream(String path)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.<>c.<.ctor>b__15_0(String x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__66`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__66`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ImmutableArrayExtensions.AsImmutableOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.WithReferences(IEnumerable`1 references)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CommonWithReferences(IEnumerable`1 newReferences)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.PrepareNewCompilation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions)
```

**Need help/suggestions**

Comment: use [Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition) the old one is deprecated now and no longer updated. if you still have issues, create a new issue [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/issues)

Answer (score 2):

My workaround for this is the following:

1. Right click on the project, open Properties.
2. Change the Target Framework to .NET Framework 4
3. Rerun the Reverse Engineer Code First script.
4. Reopen project properties, change Target Framework back to what you want it to be