# how to install EF power tools for visual studio 2015 community

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

how to install entity framework power tools for visual studio 2015. i downloaded the extension and changed the version to "14.0" but the package did not install it gave me the following error , please let me know if i had to change the version from `Pro` to `Community` or any other changes for this,

When right-clicking on a C# project, the following context menu function is supported:

1. Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.

When right-clicking on a file containing a derived DbContext class, the following context menu functions are supported:

1. View Entity Data Model XML - Displays the EDMX XML representing the underlying Code First model.
2. View Entity Data Model DDL SQL - Displays the DDL SQL corresponding to the SSDL in the underlying EDM Model.
3. Generate Views - Generates pre-compiled views used by the EF runtime to improve start-up performance. Adds the generated views file to the containing project.

```
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - -------------------------------------------
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - Initializing Install...
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - Extension Details...
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Identifier         : 2b119c79-9836-46e2-b5ed-eb766cebbf7c
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Name               : Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Author             : Microsoft
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Version            : 0.9.0.0
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Description        : Preview of useful design-time features for DbContext.
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Locale             : en-US
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   MoreInfoURL        : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=327691
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0]
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   SignatureState     : InvalidSignature
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Supported Products : 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -           Version : [10.0]
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -           Version : [11.0]
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -           Version : [12.0]
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   References         : 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       -------------------------------------------------------
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Version      : [10.0,)
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       MoreInfoURL  : 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -       Nested       : No
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - Signature Details...
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM -   Extension is signed with an invalid signature.
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - 
7/5/2016 1:36:56 AM - Searching for applicable products...
7/5/2016 1:36:57 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
7/5/2016 1:36:57 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
7/5/2016 1:36:57 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
7/5/2016 1:36:57 AM - Found installed product - ssms
7/5/2016 1:36:57 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Have you tried the instructions at, http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Entity Framework Power Tools in Visual Studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999235/how-to-use-entity-framework-power-tools-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: I'm confused.  Review my edit to make sure I didn't screw things up.  Looked like you had part of your question in the middle of the log.  I pulled that out and put it above the log messages, but I'm not sure if that stuff wasn't part of the log.

Answer (score 2):

please find the solution here below in the link

i some how figured out, and by the way also use winzip or winrar rather than zip for zipn and extraction, may be its werid but it works

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zw7qvgifwrxzqtb/AAC7Way10wpYGR2_E-BFXB7wa?dl=0