# Trying to get Reverse POCO Generator to work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried following this:
[How to use Entity Framework Power Tools in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999235/how-to-use-entity-framework-power-tools-in-visual-studio-2015)

Basically, from what I understand, I need to install EF Powertools on VS15 in order for the Reverse POCO to work. However, when I try to install the extension I get the error:

> the extension is already installed to all applicable products.

Thanks

EDIT: I finally managed to re-install the EF Powertools, but I continue to get the same errors:
'Failed to resolve include text for file: ...\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' and the other error is: 'Loading the include file 'EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned null or an empty string. The transformation will not be run.'

Answer (score 3):

You ***don't*** need to install EF Power tools. Now with VS 2015 you can use **EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator** directly.

> Reverse engineers an existing database and generates EntityFramework
>   Code First POCO classes, Configuration mappings and DbContext.

**Steps :**

- In Visual Studio 2015, right click project and select "add - new item".
- Select Online, and search for "reverse poco". Or you can download it
  from this page (use Download button at the top). By downloading and
  installing it, it will be permanently available in your "Add item"
  templates.

Here is the link : [**EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838)

Comment: The reason I asked for this is because when I try to do this, I get an error  'Failed to resolve include text for file ...CS.ttinclude'

Comment: 'Failed to resolve include text for file: .\..\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude'
and the other error is: 'Loading the include file 'EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned null or an empty string. The transformation will not be run.'

Comment: didn't you just say that's not necessary?

Comment: Actuality you have to remove any exiting old Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4.And after that try to install POCO generator.I'll remove above comment. That is a mistake.sorry for that :)

Comment: same problems, no change

Comment: Please put your issue here.That is original repo of the product.https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/issues

Comment: Side Question: has EF Reverse POCO gone PAID only recently? As of now, there is V3.0 and needs paid license.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all instances of visual studio
2. Install the .vsix from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator)
3. Open your solution, right click on a folder and select "Add > New Item..."
4. Under Installed, Select "Visual C#" (Do not select any of the sub items, like "Code" or "Data")
5. Find "EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator" in the list, if your "Sort by:" is "Default" you should see it in the list after the MVC 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

**VS 2017**

1. Add a new .net core console app
2. Install EF Core nuget -->    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
3. Just add old style app.config
4. restart VS 2017
5. Add new item to project and you will see the reverse poco generator
6. open the .tt file you had created
7. uncomment the settings.connectionstring and providername and just code it there and pick a connectionstring name
8. change other settings as desired.
9. Ctrl + S  -  as this save fires off the generation of the schema pocos.

Comment: I have tried this in VS 2019 and in a simple empty console app. but it does nothing and do not know if it even shows any warning or error or any msg