# Entity Framework Power Tools not generating entity data model in visual studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, ef-power-tools

I have installed EF Power tools on VS 2015 as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002166/1977871)

But when I try to generate entity data model for a dbcontext, I get error.

I have all the relevant assembly references.

What am I missing.

[image: Entity Framework power tools view entity data model]

[image: Entity Framework power tools view entity data model error message]

Comment: Are you abel to run and build your project?

Comment: Yes, I am able to build and run the project without any problem.